# Local database loses connection when building

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Im using a local sql database in visualstudio and I get no error messages. But whenever I build it loses connection to the database and changes doesn't get saved.

Comment: please bind your code...

Comment: There is really no code yet. No code is calling it or anything. The second the program starts it loses connection with the database.

Comment: without code how can someone understand you, update your code or you will be down voted..

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I haven't written any code on the project yet. I've only connected the database with visual studios own interface and when it runs it loses the connection. I've retried but no change.